# How to show a user how to write a letter in android?

Tags: android

I am working on a language Learning android app. I want to include a feature on how to write a particular letter of a particular language.
So, the general idea is when a user clicked on a letter say 'A',a pop up activity appears and A is written with a pencil, i.e., sort of showing the user how to write A.

Any one had idea how i can implement this in android?

thanks

Comment: make GIFs (like these http://www.handwritingforkids.com/handwrite/cursive/animation/images/animationl_a.gif) , show them using https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable

Comment: create short videos and play them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to draw letter on [canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html), using [Android drawing APIs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/package-summary.html). You can do it in two steps:

First draw letter, and save all drawing objects.
Second, draw again (replay) using previously saved objects.

There is an other way which will be easy but it will require alot of effort by designer. You will have to create gif files for each letter from which you can animation.

Comment: I used GIF .. is there a way to freeze frames, i want to play one frame, freeze it and show the next one. @penguin